# WebKit vs Mozilla vertical alignment of font glyphs in box

Tags: css, html, webkit, mozilla, vertical-alignment

[image: Glyphs in Box]

This test image shows how wildly different Safari positions text inside a box vs Firefox (Safari 5.0.5 and Firefox 5.0.1 for Mac OS X 10.6.7). Notice how the "S" for `sans-serif` is butted up to the top of the box in Firefox and not Safari. The difference seem to vary depending on typeface used, where some are even consistently rendered.

I've read [people saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880459/vertical-alignment-text-in-container-webkit-vs-firefox/5883303#5883303) that this is because of rounding issues between `font-size` and `line-height` (and fixed by setting smaller height than size), but I think that's disproved by my example where sans-serif/helvetica in Firefox always aligns top in the box.

To me it looks like Safari gets it more right than Firefox, i.e. text is generally more around a middle line.

Is there a good way to get them more consistent? My target is only standards-compliant browsers.

- NB1: This has nothing to do with `vertical-align`.
- NB2: I investigated a [similar problem in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325440/does-webkit-have-a-clipping-bug/4325791) with no completely satisfactory outcome.

My test code: http://jsbin.com/omaboc

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
              font-size: 50px;
              line-height: 1em;
            }
            div {
            background: #b5e260;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="font-family: sans-serif">Some text @ this box</div>
        <div style="font-family: serif">Some text @ this box</div>
        <div style="font-family: arial">Some text @ this box</div>
        <div style="font-family: helvetica">Some text @ this box</div>
        <div style="font-family: courier">Some text @ this box</div>
        <div style="font-family: georgia">Some text @ this box</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same problem does not happen on Windows 7, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xQmTe.gif

Comment: Exciting. The plot thickens! +1 for GIF-animation ;)

Comment: Check out the accepted answer to this puppy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155174/inconsistent-font-size-and-indentation-on-firefox-chrome

Comment: this is total garbage and impossible to design around. i feel your pain

Comment: I had the same problem https://jsfiddle.net/y5ofqfn7/1/ the position difference between firefox and safari was 7px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunetly, there isn't a solution to this problem. Text rendering is done differently in almost every browser, and even between major browser versions it sometimes changes. In some browsers it is determined by the particular font rendering systems and settings from the OS. There have always been and always will be trade offs for one type of font rendering to another, and every one of those will change with different types of displays on different types of hardware.

Sorry, you'll have to live with non-pixel perfect fonts between browsers until there is a complete monopoly by a single browser, a single OS with no available display setting choices, a single monitor type and size, and a single video card. In other words, it's never going to match pixels perfectly as long as your site supports multiple devices, browsers, displays, etc.

(Kudos for doing your own homework and testing first though. Your question was well researched and thought before asking. I wish we could have given you a better answer after all that work.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Reset at the top of your stylesheet file??

The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

You can find the explanation & the code here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I hope this would help you!

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have indeed tried the Meyer reset, without any success.