# Inconsistent font size and indentation on Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/9JU5b/

I'm trying to make a notification icon thing that looks like this: [image]

It's a `div` with a background image that has text over it, so the HTML is just:

```
<div id="notification">
    123
</div>
```

There are two differences in the text between FF and Chrome:

1. I've set the font to 15px Arial bold, but it looks "bolder" in Firefox than in Chrome. How do I make that consistent?
2. I set `text-align: center` and used `text-indent: -1px` to fix the horizontal alignment, and messed with the `line-height` until the vertical alignment was correct. However, both the horizontal and vertical alignments are off in Firefox. How do I make the indentation consistent?

Comment: Chome and Firefox in Linux seems to display it exactly in the same way.

Comment: I just tried in windows and I don't see a clear difference between Firefox and Chrome. I also tested Opera and Safari and they look the same to me.

Comment: Even the indentation? On FF6 under Win7 it's 1px less indented horizontally and 1px more indented vertically.

Comment: Ok, if I remove the text-indent rule it seems it affects Chrome only (Linux). The "bolder" difference I was not able to see it.

Comment: @lepe: It's a Windows only thing.

Comment: I think it has to be with the font and the number you are using. Try setting the width to a even number (28px) and instead of "123" use "888". Remove the indent rule. You will see it displays it correctly.

Comment: If that was the case, I would recommend to use a monospace font to achieve a consistent centering.

Comment: In windows indent and character spacing look different when using Arial. It seems consistent if font is monospace. Looks better if you use size 12px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't fix **1**.

The reason for the differences is that Firefox uses "DirectWrite" - a different technique to render text than Chrome does.

Read more here: http://www.basschouten.com/blog1.php/font-rendering-gdi-versus-directwrite

And read this, particularly the "Hinting and spacing differences" section: http://blog.mozilla.com/nattokirai/2011/08/11/directwrite-text-rendering-in-firefox-6/

To fix **2**, try setting a `line-height` in `px` (`20px` looks good). To fix the horizontal alignment, remove the `text-indent` and adjust the `width` slightly (`28px` looks good).

You should also add a bit more spacing around the text. I think this quick mockup looks better:

[image]

Comment: Snap, had just come back to edit that I changed it to px, I presume it's a difference in rounding? Is changing the width to an even number a rounding issue also?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's a rounding issue insofar as they both handle it slightly differently.

Comment: I had this issue with large text(50px). The 'font-weight' was set to 800, and for MOZ and IE9 I changed the weight to 700. I used this to format in my CSS http://stackoverflow.com/a/3387859/684966